# How does a DCOS local universe handle docker resources used by packages?

Tags: docker, mesos, mesosphere, dcos

I have DCOS installed behind a firewall where there is no internet access.  I want to be able to install packages into the cluster (e.g. Kafka) and so I have built a local universe, using the instructions [here](https://docs.mesosphere.com/1.9/installing/custom/deploying-a-local-dcos-universe/).

When I build the local universe (from a computer with internet access and by cloning the universe repo on [Github](https://github.com/mesosphere/universe)), I see the script causes the downloading of resources (URL resources defined in the `resource.json` file as well as docker images).  The process creates a file that I am able to upload to the DCOS cluster as a local universe.

However, when I try to install packages into the DCOS cluster from this local universe, not all of them install.  The ones that fail seem to rely on docker images, and I see an error message in the mess logs that looks like:

```
Container xxx for executor yyy of framework zzz failed to start. Failed to perform 'curl': curl: 96) Could not resolve host: registry-1.docker.io
```

The cluster appears to be trying to reach the Docker registry, which of course it can't, as it's behind the corporate firewall.  This appears to relate to [MESOS-6810](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MESOS-6810), which simply says that the mesos cluster should be run with `--docker-registry` pointing to a local docker registry.  I have yet to reinstall the DCOS cluster from scratch with the `[cluster_docker_registry_url][4]` installation config option pointing to a local docker registry.

My question is why does the build process for a local universe download docker images when the installation process for a package then tries to download docker images too? The packages I want to have available to be installed inside the cluster result in a local universe of 9 GB. I'm trying to understand under what circumstances DCOS will attempt to contact hosts outside the cluster.

Comment: Can you say which package is affected?

Comment: This particular package is Flink, but I see other packages like Elastic trying to reach external resources.

Comment: Hi Jhon,

  I just wanna install DC/OS with firewall enabled in offline mode(without internet access) by following Advanced Installation, I installed DC/OS in offline mode but disable & stoped firewall.
In Instructions suggested to disable & stop the firewalld, Can we install DC/OS? instead of stoping & disabling firewalld DC/OS by enabling list of portsin iptables/firewall(https://dcos.io/docs/1.8/administration/installing/ports/)? 
Can you tell us How did you installed DC/OS behind firewall or Can you give us hint to how can organise?